# How to reset/restart viewcontroller in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to have a button on my navigation bar "Reset" and I would like this to be connected to an `IBAction` to sort of "restart" the controller.

I have some segues from another controller that changes some aspects of the `viewcontroller` (that has a `collectionview`) and I want the user to be able to start over. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 15):

If you embed navigation controller to your view controller then you can use this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
let viewcontrollers = self.navigationController.viewControllers
viewcontrollers.removeLast()
viewcontrollers.append(vc)
self.navigationControllers?.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers, animate: true)
```

Comment: I didn't embed.

Answer (score 2):

You can change rootViewController of your application:

`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UIViewController()`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in Swift 2.1 with my Home view inside a `UINavigationController`:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController")
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(homeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```