# How do I restart or reset a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

So I am making an interactive story programmatically and I want a way to restart the game. (i.e clear everything) the only thing that I have found is

```
func refreshView() ->() {

    // Calling the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods to "refresh" the VC and run through the code within the methods themselves
    self.viewDidLoad
    self.viewWillAppear

}

func refreshVC(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.refreshView()
}
```

except it is saying "expression resolves to an unused function" Anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: The immediate problems are that the `refreshView()` method does not need to return anything. So delete `-> ()`. Next, `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()` need `()` on the end. You have a bigger problem though, I think. This probably isn't the best way to go about "resetting." You could try removing the current view controller and adding a new view controller of the same type. You could try removing the current window and adding a new window in your app delegate (essentially restarting the whole app). We can't know the best answer without knowing your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset/restart viewcontroller in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633566/how-to-reset-restart-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: FYI - never call `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or any other view controller life cycle method yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `()` after `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

EDIT: Okay, adding the parentheses will make your code compile. But after actually looking at it, it sounds like what you *really* want to do is to call `setNeedsDisplay()` on the view, which will cause the entire view to be re-displayed.